# Write to a Directory as a Specific User on a Different Domain

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, windows-authentication

I am wondering, how would one write a file (say for instance, from a Console Application in a scheduled task) to another computer on a different domain? How would one set the Username and Password, such as with the "Log on to..." dialog to authenticate?

Couple of prerequisites exist, obviously:

- The machines can see each other across the domains, however they need to authenticate
- You know the login details
- The username you would log in with has the appropriate permissions to write

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach here is to use [Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate(VS.71).aspx).  Have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/03/21/400088.aspx) for a straightforward how-to.

Essentially, you need to obtain a handle to the user token (usually using [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx)), and then call [`Impersonate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx).

There are also several projects (eg [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx)) to make the process a little easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Always wanted to learn Impersonation and never got around to it, I didn't know it was so simple. Thanks again Nader.