# How can i write to shared folder through Process running with LocalSystem account

Tags: wcf, shared-directory

I have WCF Service hosted with "LocalSystem" Account, This will create zip file which needs to be write to network share path(Eg:-\INGBTCPIC3xxx\Shared Folder)

I use File.Create() Method to create, But it throws an Exception System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.

I know that folder has to be shared to write to it, Please let me know with which user folder needs to be shared. Because in my case WCF service is configured to run under LocalSystem a/c

Please suggest some idea

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The domain seems to different for the account which is running WCF service and the shared location.
You can use impersonate to resolve this issue: [Write to a Directory as a Specific User on a Different Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598898/write-to-a-directory-as-a-specific-user-on-a-different-domain)

or use as batch command:
net use  /user:username password

And then use File.Create method to write the file.

Comment: Thanks, But Domain is same in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I learned how to share folder to a LocalSystem Account i.e. share with hostname of system on which WCF service is running rightclick folder-->Properties-->Sharing-->Share-->Type Hostname followed by $(xxxx$) and give Read\Write access